# How to bring fork up to date to make clean pull requests?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I am making contributions to an open source repo on a forked copy on [github](https://github.com/edlongman/inet)

I normally only fix the odd bug as I find it so every few months, in the mean time lots of other developmnent happens. I made pull requests into my fork to get the new changes.

Now they appear in my [pull requests back to the original repo](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/pull/682).
[image]

How do I make clean pull requests that only contain commits with each fix? I have tried git fetching the original repo locally and doing a merge from that but I got the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr: Branch off upstream/master. Don't commit to your local master.

If your branch has local changes and you just merge with upstream you'll still have those local changes. When you submit a PR based on this merged master it will contain those local changes.

Let's demonstrate. Here's what you look like after merging with local changes.

```
# Your situation after merging with local changes.
# D - E - F are new changes from upstream.
# 1 - 2 - 3 is your local changes.

A - B - C - D - E - F [upstream/master]
         \           \
          1 - 2 - 3 - M [master]
```

Now you make a branch off master and add some commits.

```
A - B - C - D - E - F [upstream/master]
         \           \
          1 - 2 - 3 - M [master]
                       \
                        4 - 5 - 6 [feature]
```

If you submit feature as a PR with upstream/master as the base, it will drag in 1 - 2 - 3 as well as 4 - 5 - 6, because those all contain differences from upstream/master.

This is why one avoids committing directly to master, you no longer have a common base for new branches. Instead, do all your work in branches and submit them as PRs.

---

The simplest and safest thing is to branch your work off upstream/master instead of master. Then it doesn't matter what state your fork is in.

```
$ git checkout -b feature upstream/master
# then make a few commits

                      4 - 5 - 6 [feature]
                     /
A - B - C - D - E - F [upstream/master]
         \           \
          1 - 2 - 3 - M [master]
```

If you have an existing branch off master, rebase it onto upstream/master. This will rewrite each commit as if you'd written it on top of upstream/master. There may be conflicts, fix them as needed.

```
# Before with feature based on master.

A - B - C - D - E - F [upstream/master]
         \           \
          1 - 2 - 3 - M [master]
                       \
                        4 - 5 - 6 [feature]

# Rebase onto upstream/master the commits from master to feature.
$ git rebase --onto upstream/master master feature

                      4A - 5A - 6A [feature]
                     /
A - B - C - D - E - F [upstream/master]
         \           \
          1 - 2 - 3 - M [master]
                       \
                        4 - 5 - 6
```

The original 4 - 5 - 6 will eventually be deleted.

---

To restore your fork's master, return your `master` to your upstream's master.

First, make a new branch at your existing master to preserve any local changes.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git branch dev  # or whatever you want to call it

A - B - C - D - E - F [upstream/master]
         \           \
          1 - 2 - 3 - M [master]
                        [dev]
```

Now any local changes you made to master will be preserved in your `dev` branch. You can call it anything you like, but avoid a branch name that already exists upstream.

Then move your local master to your upstream's master.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard upstream/master

                      [master]
A - B - C - D - E - F [upstream/master]
         \           \
          1 - 2 - 3 - M [dev]
```

Branches in Git are just labels that point at commits. `git reset` is how you move them around as you like. This is moving your local master to where upstream/master is pointing. `--hard` refers to what to do about the staging area and checked out files (working copy). `--hard` says to also reset them to upstream/master.

Now your master is their upstream/master. dev has your local changes to master.

Finally, push your new local master up to origin. Since it moved it will have to be forced. *Do not use --force* use the safer [`git push --force-with-lease`](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/force-with-lease/).

If you want to update your local master, simply `git pull`. A `git pull` is just a `git fetch` plus a `git merge`. We'll do a `git pull` as two separate steps to demonstrate.

```
# Fetch new commits, that's G and H.
$ git fetch upstream

                      G - H [upstream/master]
                     /
A - B - C - D - E - F [master]
         \           \
          1 - 2 - 3 - M [dev]

$ git checkout master
$ git merge upstream/master

                            [master]
                      G - H [upstream/master]
                     /
A - B - C - D - E - F
         \           \
          1 - 2 - 3 - M [dev]
```

Since master is a direct ancestor of upstream/master no merge commit is necessary. Git will "fast-forward" master to upstream/master.

Comment: Very thorough and helpful.

The key concepts I needed were rebase and properly using the upstream tag. Thanks!